# TeeChart 8 Unicode under Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, unicode, teechart

I've just installed TeeChart 8 for Delphi 2007.

All captions and titles are String values like in previous TChart control that comes with Delphi 2007.

Does someone know if there is a version of TChart that could run Widestrings on Delphi 2007?

Answer (score 0):

Delphi didn't include full Unicode support until Delphi 2009. TeeChart fully supports Unicode in Delphi 2009 and later. In Delphi 2007 you can plot Unicode text directly to the chart canvas using provided methods.